# Enable/disable buffered rendering at runtime

Tags: extjs

I have a grid that is using a buffered renderer.

For printing, I copy the grid DOM into a new window, and send it to printer. For this to work, the DOM has to be rendered completely, but with a buffered renderer, it isn't.

If I have to, I will disable buffered renderer completely, but since only a few users use the printing feature, I would prefer not to.

Is there a possibility to switch bufferedRenderer off temporarily before fetching the DOM, and to switch it back on afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure how it helps you , but I have done this similar sort by increasing the view size at runtime.

Lets suppose you have buffered renderer with this config:

```
ptype : 'bufferedrenderer',
trailingBufferZone : 20, 
leadingBufferZone : 50
```

So dynamically , you can set the viewsize at runtime by getting the reference of plugin and using setViewSize(newSize) method.

eg:

```
var dd=Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#ExampleTreePanel")[0];
var bufferedRendererPlugin = dd.plugins[0];
bufferedRendererPlugin.setViewSize(100000);
```

This large size is just a big number we can assume so that the DOM will be completely loaded and you can give it to print.Its a workaround. Again you can resize the view by setting it to small number.

```
bufferedRendererPlugin.setViewSize(115);
```

Comment: Which version of ExtJS have you used? The idea was good, but I have the problem that the view doesn't refresh correctly. In my ExtJS 6.0.1 app, the grid-item-container contains the full DOM of all entries, but also contains `style="width: 665px; transform: translate3d(0px, 19710px, 0px);"`, which makes for an odd 18 empty pages between the grid header and the grid content. I am not sure whether this is a bug in ExtJS or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the good answer by Saloo to work around some things that are different between ExtJS 6 and ExtJS 4:

```
// Set view size to match store content:
this.bufferedRenderer.setViewSize(this.getStore().getCount());
// Refresh view, so that everything is rendered:
this.bufferedRenderer.refreshView(0);
// refreshView does not revert the node container's "translate" setting after the viewSize was changed to be equal or greater than the store count, so we have to enforce it manually:
this.getView().getEl().down(this.getView().getNodeContainerSelector()).translate(0,0,0);
```